# Rails 4: View Doesn't Scroll when using One Page Scroll v1.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, plugins

Hello  I am using Rails and I am trying to use the One Page Scroll plugin shown here: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

I have a almost vanilla blank app (in terms of views and stylesheets). Here is the layout and view of the page that does not currently scroll:

`layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lorem</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='main'> <!--One Page! -->
    <div class='row'>
      <div id='tasmbloch'>
        <div id='id'>
          <%= image_tag 'ban_Trans.png' %>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   <%= yield %>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding view:

```
<div class='section'>
       <%= image_tag "lorem_borem.png"%>
</div>
<div class='section'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
```

And I have including in the my `app/assets/` javascripts and stylesheets directories the javascript and 
css corresponding to the one page scroll. I wrote a `console.log()` statement in the jQuery snippet that invokes the plugin to confirm that it was getting called, and it is.

Here is the one page scroll css that is included indirectly via `application.css`

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
}

body, .onepage-wrapper, html {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.onepage-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
}

.onepage-wrapper .section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}

.onepage-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
.onepage-pagination li {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.onepage-pagination li a{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;

}
.onepage-pagination li a:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

.onepage-pagination li a.active:before{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -4px;
  left: 8px;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll, .disabled-onepage-scroll .wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper .section {
  position: relative !important;
  top: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-pagination {
      display: none;
    }

```
body.disabled-onepage-scroll, .disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper, html {
  position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to call the CSS file in your <head>? Check the height of the body as well.

Comment: yes but I think that is done when you include application with the `stylesheet_link_tag`.

Comment: pretty sure that includes all stylesheets recursively.

Comment: the height is set to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know this is an old post, but ran into the same problem.  I think your issue was because you Got the plugin to work doing the following:

Call the function in the `<head></head>`, not footer:

```
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
            sectionContainer: "section",
            easing: "ease",

            animationTime: 1000,
            pagination: true,
            updateURL: false,
            beforeMove: function(index) {},
            afterMove: function(index) {},
            loop: false,
            keyboard: true,
            responsiveFallback: false,
            direction: "vertical"
        });
...
</script>
```

Everything worked like a charm for me from there.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `overflow: hidden` in the `body`. Try `overflow: auto`

Comment: Thanks appostolis but that Did not work. Also, since this is CSS that comes with the plugin, I imagine I don't need to change any of that as it should (and has historically with other peopls rails projects) work out of the box.

Comment: and that is precisely why this is particularly frustrating :(

Comment: hmmm yeah I thought maybe the Rails's CSS overwrites something from the plugin. Maybe it's worth trying to contact with the creator of the plugin?